# Send http request to Firebase not found

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I develop an android application that send notification to a group of user.
I have store the token in my database on server app and i refresh it correctly; everything works infact when i send notification by firebase console my device receive it. 
The problem rise when i send from my server app request to Firebase Server.
The query that select the token of the user returns the tokens correctly but my device don't receive anything.
see the posted code below:

```
<?php
require_once 'Firebase.php';
require_once 'Push.php'; 
require_once('DB_Connect.php');
$db = new DB_Connect();
$conn = $db->connect();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['campo']) && isset($_POST['data']) && isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['da'])){

    // receiving the post params
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $campo = $_POST['campo'];
    $da = $_POST['da'];
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO reservation values (null,'". $data."','". $da. "','". $user_id."','". $campo. "')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result) {
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM reservation,users,campo WHERE IDRes = (select max(IDRes) from reservation) and campo.id_campo = reservation.Campo and users.id = reservation.Utente";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

        $prefquery = "select users.firebase_token as token from users,favourite where".$row["da"]." >= favourite.da and ((".$row["da"]."+1) <= favourite.a) and favourite.giorno ='". $row["data"]."' and favourite.Utente != ".$row["id"]." and favourite.Utente = users.id";
        $resultquery = $conn->query($sql1);

        $tokens = array(); 
        while($token = $resultquery->fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($tokens, $token['token']);
        }
        $messageText = "Attenzione! è stato prenotato un campo alle ore".$row["da"]." il giorno ".$row["data"].", contrassegnato da te come preferito. Controlla le ore rimaste e sbrigati a prenotare!"; 

        $push = new Push(
           $_POST['title'],
           $_POST['message']
        );

        //getting the push from push object
        $mPushNotification = $push->getPush(); 

       //creating firebase class object 
       $firebase = new Firebase(); 

       //sending push notification and displaying result 
       $firebase->send($tokens, $mPushNotification);

        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $result1->fetch_assoc();
            $response["Reservation"]["ID_Res"] = $row["IDRes"];
            $response["Reservation"]["data"] = $row["data"];
            $response["Reservation"]["da"] = $row["da"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Field"]["IDCampo"] = $row["id_campo"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Field"]["NomeCampo"] = $row["nome_campo"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Utente"]["IDUtente"] = $row["id"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Utente"]["fullname"] = $row["fullname"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Utente"]["email"] = $row["email"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Utente"]["gender"] = $row["gender"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Utente"]["picture"] = $row["profile_picture_url"];
            $response["Reservation"]["Utente"]["data_nascita"] = $row["data_nascita"];
        }
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
      // user failed to store
      $response["error"] = TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters  is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Firebase.php

```
<?php 

define('FIREBASE_API_KEY', 'myserverkey');
class Firebase {

    public function send($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    /*
    * This function will make the actuall curl request to firebase server
    * and then the message is sent 
    */
    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

        //firebase server url to send the curl request
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        //building headers for the request
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        //Initializing curl to open a connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //Setting the curl url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        //setting the method as post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        //adding headers 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //disabling ssl support
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        //adding the fields in json format 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        //finally executing the curl request 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        //Now close the connection
        curl_close($ch);

        //and return the result 
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Push.php

```
<?php 

class Push {
    //notification title
    private $title;

    //notification message 
    private $message;

    //notification image url 
    private $image;

    //initializing values in this constructor
    function __construct($title, $message) {
         $this->title = $title;
         $this->message = $message; 
         $this->image = null; 
    }

    //getting the push notification
    public function getPush() {
        $res = array();
        $res['data']['title'] = $this->title;
        $res['data']['message'] = $this->message;
        $res['data']['image'] = $this->image;
        return $res;
    }

}
?>
```

Android code-> Class extends FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String messageTitle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_app)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.icon_app));
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

FirebaseMessagingService 
I hope that anyone can help me because i'm stuck and i can't go on.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Simone. In your server-side code, you're only sending a `data`-only payload. When using the Firebase Console, the message is treated as a `notification` payload. See the difference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages). Can you post your client side (Android) code? Maybe you're only handling messages with `notification` payloads. :)

Comment: I add the code of android client; The log in onMessageReceived() method is not print in android monitor. means that no message arrived at device.

Comment: despite i use data payload, if i modify my android client code so:JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            title = json.getString("title");
            message = json.getString("message"); the String are empty

Comment: Hmm. Odd. Even the `From` doesn't show up? Can you try sendinga message using cURL? See if it's the same case?